# Implementation of multiple pipelines and command executions in C

Tags: c, linux, unix, pipe

I have a homework that asks me to create a shell that executes multiple commands separated by pipelines. Here is my code snippet for forking childs and executing the commands:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < commands; i++) {

        place = commandStarts[i];

        if((pid = fork()) < 0) exit(1);
        else if (pid == 0) {
            if(i < pipe_counter && dup2(fds[j + 1], 1) < 0) exit(1);// If this is not the last remaining command

            if(j != 0 && dup2(fds[j-2], 0) < 0) exit(1);        // If this is not the first command

            for(int c = 0; c < 2*pipe_counter; c++) close(fds[c]);

            if(execvp(argv[place], argv+place)) exit(0);        // Execute and if it returns anything, exit!
        }
        j+=2;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < 2 * pipe_counter; i++) close(fds[i]);

    while ((wait(&status)) != pid);                     // The only program that gets to this point is the 
                                        //     parent process, which should wait for completion
```

Even though, it seems to be working just fine in simple examples, in some more complex, the grading system gives me this **HINT: You should wait for ALL processes in a pipe chain to terminate before displaying the prompt, no just for the last one!**

Can you tell where my mistake is?

Comment: Where in the code is  where you wait for each process to complete?

Comment: As you can see in the end of the snippet, I wait for all the processes to complete in one while loop!

Comment: Do you?  How does that work?...  Exactly.  I don't think it works as you think.

Comment: Well, for simple (and small examples. like: ls | wc | wc) it works just fine, what do you mean you don't think it works as I think? Can you give an example?

Comment: Think about which `pid` value is it looping for.

Comment: For the pid of the last process, right? Why is this a mistake?

Comment: Where does it wait for the previous-to-last process to exit?

Comment: If, I add an else statement in the for loop (to let only the parent execute that) and then add inside a wait(NULL) and waits for ever! I can't seem to find what's wrong with that!!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the answer is in the question.

Comment: As you can see Joshua my friend, the answer isn't in the question. Next time don't just compile and run the code, but rather try to understand the problem first before flagging anything!!

Comment: Note that there is no need to test the return value from `execvp()` or any of its relatives: if the function returns, it failed; if it succeeds, it does not return.  It is also conventional to at least indicate failure with `exit(EXIT_FAILURE);` or some other non-zero exit status.  Often, it's a good idea to report which command failed — print an error message with at least the name of the command, and probably the error message corresponding to `errno`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, my mistake was that I was waiting for only the last forked child to terminate.

Here is the correct code snippet that waits for **every** child to terminate:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < commands; i++) {

        place = commandStarts[i];

        if((pid = fork()) < 0) exit(1);
        else if (pid == 0) {
            if(i < pipe_counter && dup2(fds[j + 1], 1) < 0) exit(1);// If this is not the last remaining command

            if(j != 0 && dup2(fds[j-2], 0) < 0) exit(1);            // If this is not the first command

            for(int c = 0; c < 2*pipe_counter; c++) close(fds[c]);

            if(execvp(argv[place], argv+place)) exit(1);            // Execute and if it returns anything, exit!
        }
        j+=2;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < 2 * pipe_counter; i++) close(fds[i]);

    for(int i = 0; i < commands; i++) wait(&status);            // The only program that gets to this point is the 
                                                                //     parent process, which should wait for completion.
```

Also many thanks to [wallyk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/198536/wallyk) for helping me think this through!

Comment: While this is a lot closer to a robust implementation, it has the disadvantage that it will be derailed by any grandchildren which are reaped by `wait()`.  You could track the children's pids as generated and have the wait loop wait for those specific ids.